# add class to element with a certain parent div (not applying all divs with same parent name)

Tags: javascript

I've been struggling with this piece of code:

```
<div class="parent">
  <tr>
    <td class="box">
    <td class="box">
  </tr>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <tr>
    <td class="box">
    <td class="box">
  </tr>
</div>
```

So what I want is that when I click on the first parent, first box, that it gives a class to that box. But when you click on the second parent, second box, that it gives a class to that box and also keep the first box of the first parent enabled.

I have a piece of javascript, but it also disables the click on the first parent when I click on the second parent.

```
     $(".box").click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
        $('.box').removeClass('boxActive');
        $(this).addClass("boxActive");
});
```

Hope someone could help me out!

Apreciate it and thanks!!

Comment: Why did you put ` e.preventDefault();` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is too confusing.
Firstly, you can not use `tr` `td` tags where ever you want. It should be enclosed inside `<table>` tag.

Secondly, You are not closing `<td>` tags.

I removed `tr` and replaced all `td` with div and it works.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="box">11</div>
    <div class="box">12</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="box">21</div>
    <div class="box">22</div>
</div>
```